# Using WiX, how to skip a component when a certain registry key does not exist?

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I want to copy some files into a directory in another product's installation tree, but only if that product is installed.  So I figured I could set a property based on a registry search to find that product's installation root.  Then I could use the property in a condition element on the component element.

Here is my code.  For some reason, I am getting an error when the other product is not installed and the registry search comes up empty since the registry key will not be found.

```
<Property Id="PRODUCTPATH">
  <RegistrySearch Id="PRODUCTPATH" Root="HKLM" Key="_MY_KEY_" Name="_MY_NAME_" Type="raw" />
</Property>

<SetProperty Id="PRODUCTBINPATH" Value="[PRODUCTPATH]\BIN" After="AppSearch"/>

<Component Id="CommonDLLs" Guid="_MY_GUID_" Directory="INSTALLLOCATION">
  <Condition>PRODUCTPATH</Condition>
  <RegistryValue Id="_MY_ID_" Root="HKLM" Key="_MY_KEY_2" Name="Installed" Value="1" Type="integer" KeyPath="yes" />
  <CopyFile Id="myfile1.dll" FileId="myfile1.dll" DestinationProperty="PRODUCTPATH" DestinationName="myfile1.dll"/>
  <CopyFile Id="myfile2.dll" FileId="myfile2.dll" DestinationProperty="PRODUCTPATH" DestinationName="myfile2.dll"/>
</Component>
```

Comment: what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: Try giving `<Condition><![CDATA[PRODUCTPATH]]></Condition>` instead of `<Condition>PRODUCTPATH</Condition>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, all you have to do is add a condition to the SetProperty element like this:

```
<Property Id="PRODUCTPATH">
```

```
<SetProperty Id="PRODUCTBINPATH" Value="[PRODUCTPATH]\BIN" After="AppSearch">PRODUCTPATH</SetProperty>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the util:RegistrySearch instead of RegistrySeach
This element comes with Util Extension. Check [here](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/general/extension_usage_introduction.html) if you don't know how to use extensions.

The util:RegistrySearch has an attribute (Result) for only checking if the key exists or not.

It would be like that:

```
<util:RegistrySearch
   Id="PRODUCTPATH"
   Variable="PRODUCTPATH"
   Root="HKLM" 
   Key="_MY_KEY_" 
   Format="raw"
   Result="exists">
```